# implementation of pointnet pytorch-geometric

Tags: point-clouds, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to implement Pointnet with the pytorch geometric framework

Firstly, is [these](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/conv/point_conv.html) already a full implementation of pointnet?

I already found an example of [pointnet++](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/pointnet2_classification.py) (what is an extension verson of pointnet) but could not figure out how to extract the pointnet model